# Firebase Function get url params from request

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the URL ID parameters from my Firebase function this is what I currently have

```
exports.dynamicMetaTagsUpdate = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  console.log("dynamicMetaTagsUpdate Called");

  const html = fs.readFileSync("./index.html", "utf8");
  const url = request.url;
  const urlParts = request.path.split("/");
  const id = urlParts[urlParts.length - 1];

  console.log("url " + url);
  console.log("urlParts " + urlParts);
  console.log("id " + id);
}
```

My URL output: `url /chart/?id=-MfKI_eFSOo0xzSLOxYJ`

URL parts out: `urlParts ,chart,`

The id is null and this is my full URL **https://viz.wiijii.co/chart/?id=-MfKI_eFSOo0xzSLOxYJ**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `query` parameter of `request`. It's same as ExpressJS and is also mentioned in [using Express Request and Response objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#using_express_request_and_response_objects) section of the documentation.

`console.log(request.query)` should log an object containing all query parameters.

```
const {id} = request.query
console.log(`ID: ${id}`)
```

Comment: thanks didn't know I could use express been sometime dealing with URL params